# Search in Custom ListView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, search, simpleadapter

I'm trying to do Search in my custom listview. But when text change in EditText, IF doesn't work. That's my code. I use SimpleAdapter.  What is wrong ?

> editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
>
>
>   //get the text in the EditText
>      String searchString= editText.getText().toString();
>      int textLength=searchString.length();
>
>      //clear the initial data set
>      searchResults.clear();
>
>      for(int i=0;i<docs.size();i++)
>      {
>          String playerName=docs.get(i).get(FIRST).toString();
>          if(textLength<=playerName.length()){
>              //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
>              if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
>              {
>                  searchResults.add(docs.get(i));
>                  Log.i("searchResults", docs.get(i)+"");
>
>              }
>              else Log.i("doesn't work", "doesn't work");
>     }
>      }
>
>      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
>
> adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, searchResults, R.layout.list,
>            new String[] { FIRST, LAST, DATE  }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.date });
>
>  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
>  listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
>         int arg3) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
>
> } });
> ```

Comment: Can you explain, "doesn't work"?

Comment: @codeMagic When I enter text for search in editText, I have just an empty listView.

Comment: @codeMagic my IF doesn't work, when I enter value in EditText, which equals value in my ArrayList.

Comment: Why are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` **and** reinitializing your `Adapter` every time?

Comment: @codeMagic, I must show results every time after text in editText changed.

Comment: I understand but you shouldn't need to reinitialize the `Adapter` every time. That is why you have `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @codeMagic, Okay. I remove reinitialize the Adapter in TextChangedListener. But why does my IF doesn't work?

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see what *does* happen? Such as checking your logs, checking that your values of your lists are/aren't what you expect. Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give us much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my search in listview. Using SimpleAdapter for listview.

> ```
> ListView  listView;
> SimpleAdapter adapter;
> private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> docs;
> private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> searchResults;
>
> EditText editText;
>
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
>     editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
>
>     docs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
>     // values for docs
>     getUrlDocs(false);
>
>
>     searchResults = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
>
>     editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
>
>           int textlength = editText.getText().length();
>           String searchString= editText.getText().toString();
>           searchResults.clear();
>           String attr = null;
>             for (int i = 0; i < docs.size(); i++)
>             {
>
>               attr = docs.get(i).get(FIRST).toString().trim();
>               Log.i("attr", attr+"");
>
>                 if (textlength  <= attr.length())
>                 {
>
>                     if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(attr.substring(0,textlength)))
>                     {
>                       searchResults.add(docs.get(i));
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, searchResults, R.layout.list,
>                     new String[] { FIRST, LAST, DATE  }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.date });
>
>           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
>                 int arg3) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
>
>         }
>     });
> ```
>
> }